# Efficient boolean operation of a pandas series object on a pandas dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python pandas DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
                   A      B      C    ...     Z
2012-01-01 00    True  False  False   ...   True
2012-01-02 00    True  False   True   ...  False
2012-01-03 00   False   True  False   ...  False
...              ...    ...    ...    ...   ...
2012-12-31 00   False   True  False   ...  False
```

The columns are named in alphabetical order from A to Z. I want to boolean 'and' all the columns from A to Z using column Z (i.e. pseudocode=>> new_dataframe = [A and Z, B and Z,... Y and Z, Z and Z])

Am I stuck with using a for loop to apply the boolean 'and' operation on all columns (i.e. from column A to column Z)? To reiterate my question in another manner is there an efficient way or built-in pandas function to 'AND' a pandas Series on all the columns of a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear exactly what you want to do. If you simply want to and some of the columns together, you can use the built-in method `all`, as follows (I've included some code to make this a runnable example):

```
import pandas
import numpy

a = numpy.random.rand(10, 10)>0.5
b = pandas.DataFrame(a, columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
selectedcolumns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
b['Anded'] = b[selectedcolumns].all(1)
```

If you want to "and" each of the columns with the last one, you can do

```
anded = b[selectedcolumns].apply(lambda x, y: x*y, args=[b['J']])
```

Comment: I have a different thing in mind.. sorry my question was not clear and i've just edit it. I need to get a new dataframe from my original dataframe i.e. pseudocode=>> new_dataframe = [A and Z, B and Z,... Y and Z, Z and Z] ..so I want to 'and' all the columns in the dataframe with the column named Z. Thanks

Comment: I've added that option now. I think the key in the wording would have been to say "and each of the columns with the last one".

Answer (score -1):

This has to be the strangest tech problem I have ever heard of.

Binary stuff can be hard to debug.

Karnaut Tables might help...

Comment: hi pardon me if my question seems theoretical in nature.. it's not one.. what i meant by an 'efficient way' is if there's any 'built-in function' in pandas to do what i described in question :P